# "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" exception with Picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I've music player app which interacts with RemoteControlClient. I need to load album cover image to display it in lock screen widget. I try to use Piccasso to achieve this. I've written the folowing code:

```
private final Target artworkTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        remoteControlClient.editMetadata(false).putBitmap(RemoteControlClientCompat.MetadataEditorCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTWORK,
                bitmap).apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Artwork loading failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
    }
};

...

private void playNextSong(int songPosition) {
    ...

    String artworkUrl = Constants.Urls.BASE_ARTWORK_URL + currentSong.getArtworkId();
    Picasso.with(this).load(artworkUrl).skipMemoryCache().into(artworkTarget);
    // Update the remote controls
    remoteControlClient.editMetadata(true)
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, currentSong.getArtist().getName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, currentSong.getAlbum().getName())
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, currentSong.getName())
                .apply();

   ...
   }
```

But sometimes I get exception:

```
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:772)
    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:105)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:440)
    at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:96)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1025)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13944)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3331)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2357)
    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3326)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3693)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3057)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12775)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3057)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12775)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3057)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12775)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3057)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12775)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3057)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12775)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
```

I've tried to save loaded bitmap reference in my service, but it didn't help. 
Does anybody have idea what is wrong with my code? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you're using an Android 4.3 device or newer. The RemoteControlClient implementation from 4.3 does a recycle on the artwork under certain conditions. See

http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/RemoteControlClient.java#556

You essentially have to make a copy of the bitmap you if Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. But I do not understand what do you mean by make a copy. I have a list view of images loaded with picasso and when i go to a new activity and press back key, my app crashes with the above error.

Comment: By copy, I mean

    Bitmap destBitmap = srcBitmap.copy(srcBitmap.config, false);

and use destBitmap as an argument to RemoteControlClient.

Answer (score 2):

In your `onDestory()` or `onDestroyView()` callbacks try calling `Picasso.with(Context).cancelRequest(Target);`

Credit to the guys here: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/38

Comment: I think the relevant part in this case is to use a hard reference to the target and not an anonymous instance. He's using a hard reference so maybe like you said he only has to cancel the request to prevent GC. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was call unregisterRemoteControlClient for the existing RemoteControlClient, and create a new one each time to play a new song. The problem was produced when the user try to play twice the same song, with the same cover picture of course.

The snippet which solves the problem is:

```
if(mRemoteControlClientCompat!=null){
    RemoteControlHelper.unregisterRemoteControlClient(mAudioManager, mRemoteControlClientCompat);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
intent.setComponent(mMediaButtonReceiverComponent);
mRemoteControlClientCompat = new RemoteControlClientCompat(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PlayerService.this, 0, intent, 0));
RemoteControlHelper.registerRemoteControlClient(mAudioManager, mRemoteControlClientCompat);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to run your code in separate thread and it will work

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                             /// here is your code
                              bitmap_user=transform(bitmap);
                              imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap_user);

                          }
                      });
```